# Babel and biblatex problem with TexLive 2018

Tags: biblatex, babel, texlive-2018

I have just installed TexLive 2018 on my Linux machine. I try to compile the MWE (see below), but the compilation ended with:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/inputenc.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/t1enc.def))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/switch.def)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel-slovenian/slovene.ldf
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/babel.def
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/babel/txtbabel.def))))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def)))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/pdftexcmds.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/oberdiek/kvoptions.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/kvsetkeys.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/etexcmds.sty)))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/logreq/logreq.def))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/url/url.sty)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-dm.def)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/apa.dbx)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/blx-compat.def)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.def)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/apa.bbx
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/apa.cbx)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/biblatex.cfg))
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex-apa/slovene-apa.lbx
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/slovene.lbx)
(/opt/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/slovene.lbx

! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.528 }

?
```

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[slovene]{babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa,citestyle=apa,hyperref]{biblatex}

\DeclareLanguageMapping{slovenian}{slovene-apa}

%\addbibresource{references.bib}

\title{Title of the document}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Test}

Lorem ipsum.

%\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It is important to note that the same document compiled just fine with TexLive 2017. I suspect that something is wrong with `babel`/`biblatex` settings. I kindly as for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a missing comma in `slovene.lbx` that causes this error ([specifically in line 481](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/0dcee7a78b7ac6e89e1714f4e51f8adb2a2d08fe/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/slovene.lbx#L481)).

The bug has been [reported](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/746) and [fixed](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/943d40c9804d39b386b06df26a0f58dd1c38ba40) in version 3.12 of `biblatex` (released 2018-10-30). An update should resolve the issue.

If for some reason you can not update your `biblatex` installation. You can get a fixed replacement `slovene.lbx` for 3.11 from 
https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/b14b013cce98fef41a4f8a19fdf4924facbd87cb/tex/latex/biblatex/lbx/slovene.lbx. Just drop it into the same file as your main `.tex` document. Note that this version may throw errors with older systems over missing string definitions.